# How to add google maps api key during deployment (on heroku ) and how to use development / production keys?

Tags: google-maps, heroku, development-environment, production-environment, api-key

I want to deploy something on heroku which includes a google map. 
In my script I used

```
script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

on heroku, I added to environment variables the actual google map api key I received. The map is still not showing up in production and I wonder what I did wrong.

Also, a general question as Im not too familiar with development/production variables. I understand its important for security reasons. So in my script do I have to create 2 files- 1 for production where I include the actual key and a development file which would not include the actual key? Thats what I've seen doing some research but I wonder:

1. If I do have those 2 files, how come the production script with the actual key can't be 'seen' while the development file can?
2. Do I need to create 2 scripts or can I just use a script tag (like I did with google maps) where I don't include the key and do it while deployment?

It would be cool if someone could explain this to me!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to precompile the JavaScript assets and push them to the Heroku server.

Try this:

```
rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push heroku master
git push origin master
```